# OAuth2 Authorization Code in Cookie, good or bad?

Tags: authentication, cookies, go, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I can not seem to find a SIMPLE answer to the question on how to persist OAuth2 authentication... Let's take Google+ OAuth2 API as an example.

1. User goes to page
2. User is not authenticated, and gets redirected to authentication page where he logs in
3. User logs in successfully and authorises my app
4. User gets redirect to specified (by me) URI with Authorisation Code
5. I use authorisation code to obtain a token in order to submit queries in the name of the user

All is good and well. My question is: how do you SECURELY know at step 2 that the user visiting the page is already logged in, without having to go through the whole process of redirecting him to all these pages.

I assume storing the Authorisation Code retrieved at step 4 in a cookie is not an option.

All of this will happen in a server-side (Go - if that matters) application.
Any help is much appreciated... I need a simple solution.

Thank you!

Comment: OAuth doesn't persist information. Once a user successfully completes the flow, set a cookie (secure, HTTP Only) with a sensible expiry date and generate a secure random number to associate with their account and keep them logged in. Storing a time stamp in a signed cookie can help avoid replay attacks. Look towards using http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions

Comment: I know it doesn't, thus the question :) I will look into gorilla/sessions although I'd possibly like a solution without 3rd party libs. Thanks!

Comment: Go has a http.Cookie type, but I'd be wary about rolling your own sessions store given how easy it is to mess up (signing, encryption) without knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

use server-side sessions to store any authentication state or even access tokens if you need them.

one solution is to use a database for session store (an encrypted cookie holds the session id) 
and another is to use cookie sessions (encrypted cookies that hold the session data).
using encrypted cookies that only the server is able to decrypt should be safe enough.